# How can I get debug symbols for SSMS? (prefer 17.9.1)

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2017

All of my team are supposed to have VDIs based on the same image.
Some of us (4 of 6) are having a problem.

SSMS fails with the message:

> SSMS has stopped working
>   Windows can try to restart the program.

my options are to `Restart` or `Debug`.

I upgraded in April to v17.9.1 hoping to fix the problem.

I can reproduce this regularly, but not perfectly.
Meaning that sometimes after I choose the option `restart` the problem goes away for hours.
Which is odd - haven't found a pattern or I'd be exploiting it.

I fear that I am at some "Raymond Chen" type of edge case

I'm at a loss of how to pursue this farther.

**Where can I get** a debug build or pdb or
**something that would allow me to see where the failure is** when I choose to debug the program?
(Even if it just tells me the component)

A non-public option would be acceptable (I'm an MSDN subscriber).   (There used to be "checked builds" for various things however, I don't see one for SSMS)

The only thing that is different/strange about our VDI config is that my user's storage areas ("Documents", "Pictures", +others) are redirected to a different NAS than the OS.  (A neat trick!)

---

Forgot to add that the event viewer says the issue is in wpdshext.dll
Windows 10

Comment: ssms settings are stored by default in documents? they're there/readable?

Comment: @TEEKAY Sorry, not certain where the ssms settings are.  My problem is with opening files using File Open and with the File Save As. I know that the Documents folder was moved to a different NAS because I was told and I can see it when I do properties. I think this weird thing has to do with the issue but cannot prove it.  Hope that makes more sense.  TL/DR: My issue is the program fail when using the file dialog in open or save as modes.